# Run a C++ program spread over three different directories

Tags: c++

In my terminal, I have one repository called `main_program`. The directory contains three other directories : `BornesGUI`,  `ProgrammePrincipal` and `Source`

`BornesGUI` :

```
AjoutBorneFontaineUI.cpp       BornesGUI.cpp  Makefile                           moc_SupprimerBorneUI.cpp   ui_AjoutBorneStationnementUI.h
AjoutBorneFontaineUI.h         BornesGUI.h    moc_AjoutBorneFontaineUI.cpp       nbproject                  ui_BornesGUI.h
AjoutBorneFontaineUI.ui        BornesGUI.ui   moc_AjoutBorneStationnementUI.cpp  SupprimerBorneUI.cpp       ui_SupprimerBorneinterface.h
AjoutBorneStationnementUI.cpp  build          moc_BornesGUI.cpp                  SupprimerBorneUI.h         ui_SupprimerBorneUI.h
AjoutBorneStationnementUI.h    dist           moc_predefs.h                      SupprimerBorneUI.ui
AjoutBorneStationnementUI.ui   main.cpp       moc_SupprimerBorneinterface.cpp    ui_AjoutBorneFontaineUI.h
```

`ProgrammePrincipal` :

```
build  dist  Makefile  nbproject  Utilisation.cpp
```

`Source` :

```
Borne.cpp          BorneFontaine.h         BorneStationnement.h  ContratException.h  nbproject          tests
BorneException.h   Borne.h                 build                 dist                RegistreBorne.cpp  validationFormat.cpp
BorneFontaine.cpp  BorneStationnement.cpp  ContratException.cpp  Makefile            RegistreBorne.h    validationFormat.h
```

The program is spread over three different directories. Usually I only do `g++ *.cpp` to run the program, but it seems not possible here. How can I do it?

Comment: By "repository" you mean "folder"?

Comment: run `make all`?

Comment: @bolov Yes, you are right. What is the difference?

Comment: @S.M. Can you guide step by step? Where do I need to go?

Comment: @S.M. I just ran `make all` in `Source`, but I did not get an executable file. There was no error and I was the impression it went well, but still can't find an executable file

Comment: Read the program documentation.  Make is a programming language that could put the executable literally anywhere.  Or read the Makefile

Comment: Read some documentation on [Makefiles](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Introduction.html#Introduction). You need to create a file to tell it what to do, but in the long run it's infinitely better than running `g++` by hand every time.

Comment: repository is a very specific term used in git

Comment: What about `g++ BornesGUI/*.cpp ProgrammePrincipal/*.cpp Source/*.cpp`

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is to implement some kind of build system. On Unix-like systems, this can be done with `make`. A `Makefile` may be created to do complex compilations. It looks like a `Makefile` is already included. Read the `Makefile` or the program documentation to find out where the executable is placed and what it is named.

Generally, `Makefiles` will create object files for each source file. This is done with `gcc -c`. This seperates compilation from linking. Once all the required object files are compiled, they are linked together with `gcc -o <object file list>`. Here's a short example to help your understanding:

```
SRC1 = src/main.cpp
SRC2 = src/error_handler.cpp
SRC3 = src/init.cpp
SRC4 = src/Virtual_memory.cpp
SRC5 = src/decode.cpp
SRC6 = src/file_info.cpp
OBJ1 = $(SRC1:.cpp=.o)
OBJ2 = $(SRC2:.cpp=.o)
OBJ3 = $(SRC3:.cpp=.o)
OBJ4 = $(SRC4:.cpp=.o)
OBJ5 = $(SRC5:.cpp=.o)
OBJ6 = $(SRC6:.cpp=.o)

EXE = Assembler

INSTALL_PATH = /usr/local/bin

HFILES = include/asm_defines.h include/error_handler.h include/init.h include/decode.h include/file_info.h include/buffer.h
CFLAGS = -O2
LDFLAGS =
INCDIR = -Iinclude

all : $(EXE)

$(EXE) : $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2) $(OBJ3) $(OBJ4) $(OBJ5) $(OBJ6)
    g++ -o $(EXE) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2) $(OBJ3) $(OBJ4) $(OBJ5) $(OBJ6)

$(OBJ1) : $(SRC1) $(HFILES)
    g++ $(INCDIR) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC1) -o $(OBJ1)

$(OBJ2) : $(SRC2) $(HFILES)
    g++ $(INCDIR) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC2) -o $(OBJ2)

$(OBJ3) : $(SRC3) $(HFILES)
    g++ $(INCDIR) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC3) -o $(OBJ3)

$(OBJ4) : $(SRC4) $(HFILES)
    g++ $(INCDIR) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC4) -o $(OBJ4)

$(OBJ5) : $(SRC5) $(HFILES)
    g++ $(INCDIR) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC5) -o $(OBJ5)

$(OBJ6) : $(SRC6) $(HFILES)
    g++ $(INCDIR) -c $(CFLAGS) $(SRC6) -o $(OBJ6)
```

The `$` prefixed words are variables and in this case store some filename. The primary indents follows by `:` are rules. What they essentially mean is "In order to create this, we first need this file present". So, in order to create the executable, we need the object files present. `make` will go through and create the executable (here $(EXE)) and will realize it needs the object files, and will follow the rules for creating those. Include directory make be piped into gcc with `gcc -I<include directory>`.

I now realize this answer may be a little too in-depth, but in short you should check the documentation to see how the `makefile` should be used. In the future if you write multi-file programs, you can use `gcc` and `makefiles` this way to build your programs.

Comment: I suggest using CMake or another build system as it's less tedious, and projects may be compiled on any OS.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser Yes that's a good point, I suggested Make because I have a good amount of experience in it but any build system will do.

Comment: In my experience, Make on its own has a smaller footprint and requires less maintenance. However, CMake generates _huge_ Makefiles with a few lines of code, and it scales better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CMake for this. Simply add a top-level `CMakeLists.txt` file with the following boilerplate:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(<project name>)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

Then, for `src`:

```
add_subdirectory(<directory0>)
add_subdirectory(<directory1>)
add_subdirectory(<directory2>)

add_executable(<executable name> main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(<executable name> PUBLIC <directory0>,
                                               <directory1>,
                                               <directory2>)
```

And each of the subdirectories:

```
add_library(<directory name> <sources>)
```

To setup/compile, run `cmake src -B build`. A makefile will be placed in the build directory to compile your program.

More information is available at [CMake's website](http://cmake.org).

Answer (score -1):

To extract source files from your current directory:

```
find -name '*.cpp'
```

To compile them:

```
cc -c <source files>
```

Putting it all together:

```
cc -c `find -name '*.cpp'`
```

Make sure to use backticks on the last one; it insures the shell will *run* the command inside the quotes, rather than simply returning it.